# QGIS 2.16 IDs attribute table doesn't match with the row number anymore?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-2.16

Since QGIS 2.16 the attribute tables count the rows starting with 1, on the previous versions it started with 0, so the `$ID` could match with it. Is this some kind of mistake? Do I have to use another command? Don't really understand the usefulness of this.

Answer (score 1):

By "count the rows" you probably mean *row lables*. These does not correspond with features ID at all, they are fixed and don't affect your data - try sort table by some attribute and hover with mouse over the row lables and you will see it.

[image]

So by expression `$ID` you can get exact actual id of your features starting with 0.

*Note:* Beware to use `$ID` in virtual fields, because when you for example delete a feature, this values will set to new actual features id. For more information check this question: [QGIS does not show FID field of vector data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212866/qgis-does-not-show-fid-field-of-vector-data).